# Cross platform framework

Tags: android, ios, cross-platform

I want create application for Android and iOS (phones and tablets). I would like use some cross platform framework for acceleration developing process. So I ask for some recommendation.

It will be small or medium application. It will use tandard wigets like text input, check box, radio button, list box. It would be great have input with autofocus or contextual searching.

My requirements are for framework:

- working on phone and tablets
- easy to start / install (very important)
- easy to deploy (very important)
- include library for working with images
- include library for working with fonts (TrueType)
- learn something perspective for future
- be able pack with my application some images
- i am able pay some money for comfort

I had asked google before i wrote this question. I found few frameworks but i have dubieties about all of them :).

Answer for cross plafrom framewrok are:

**Flutter**

*It is young. And is it perspective flutter & Dart?*

---

**Sencha**

*Is it easy for start and deploy?*

---

**PhoneGap**

---

**Qt**

*It is C++. How fast is it for developing?*

---

**Kivy**

---

I read their description. I checked their documentation. But I would like know opinion of people who worked with it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Man, You have two major options.

**Xamarin.native**

- If your application is supporting a high (pixel perfect) graphic
  content then go for Xamarin.Native
- All your requirement will be covered by this.
- You can share 80% of your code along all the platforms.
- Only UI related stuff is written differently for each platform.
- Everything else is shared, You can go for PCL solution
  https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/pcl/
- https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/
- https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/

**Xamarin.Forms**

- If your application is not very rich in UI.
- If your application is more of form based
- Go for Xamarin.Forms
- https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/getting-started/